# Anyway to see list of preprocessor defined macros?

Tags: gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, codesourcery

I'd like to see all macros that are defined by the invocation of the compiler I'm using.  Is there any way to do this?   I have seen in the manual it says you can use `cpp -dM`  but this doesn't work for me. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

When I run:

```
cpp -dM
```

I get no output at all from the preprocessor.  If I try adding `-dM` as an option on gcc, I don't notice any difference.

Comment: "Doesn't work for me" - please be more descriptive!

Comment: On my Linux computer, the output of `cpp -dM < /dev/null | wc -l` is `124`, so there are 124 predefined values. `cpp -dM < /dev/null | less` shows me what they are. What is the output of those commands on your computer?

Comment: Sorry I tried to clear it up a little

Comment: Rob thank you I'll have to try and figure out how to do that from windows, which unfortunately I am stuck using. I'm using code sourcery cross compiler for arm. (A gcc port essentially)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

Note that you can also get the compiler macros in addition with this command:

```
touch bla.c && gcc -dM -E bla.c
```

For example on my computer:

```
$ touch bla.c && gcc -dM -E bla.c | wc -l
486
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | wc -l
124
$
```

Comment: also useful are `-xc`, `-xc++` and `-std=...` so you can compare language and dialect-specific definitions

Comment: @Christoph actually I tried first `gcc -xc -dM -E - < /dev/null` for my second example, but this does not seem to work with `-dM` (same result as in the first example)

Comment: @Christoph ok so it has been fixed because it doesn't on my gcc-4.4.3/Linux

Answer (score 5):

By default, `cpp -dM` will read its input file from standard input and write to standard output.  Since you're not trying to preprocess any input, you can pass it the empty input using `/dev/null`:

```
# Option 1
cpp -dM < /dev/null
# Optio n2
cpp -dM /dev/null
```

On Windows, you can use the `NUL` pseudofile instead of `/dev/null`.